# MySQL weird date_add interval

Tags: mysql, date, intervals

I want to add 1 month on a datetime on MySQL 5.1.66-0+squeeze1.

When I do that :

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Result is :

```
2013-08-19 17:36:34
```

It's ok. But when I do that :

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("2013-07-19 17:37:00", INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Result is :

```
323031332d30382d31392031373a33373a3030
```

Same with :

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("2013-07-19", INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Result is :

```
323031332d30382d3139
```

I don't understand what's wrong :(

Thanks.

EDIT : I've tried this but error is the same.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("2013-07-19", INTERVAL 31 DAY)
SELECT ADDDATE("2013-07-19", 31)
```

Comment: Your examples work correctly on SQLFiddle, version 5.161 (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d41d8/234).

Comment: I'm on MySQL 5.1.66-0+squeeze1 (phpMyAdmin 4.0.3). Error with PMA ?

Comment: I updated to PMA 4.0.4.1. Same error, not PMA :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exmple works fine for me too, it can be a configuration error... try casting the result as a DATE:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD('2013-07-19', INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Comment: It works ! Thank you. But I don't understand what my first query doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    SELECT DATE_ADD("2013-07-19", INTERVAL 31 DAY)
```

EDIT:

From `MySQL 5.1.59` to `5.1.61`, a change in handling of a date-related assertion caused several functions to become more strict when passed a DATE() function value as their argument and reject incomplete dates with a day part of zero. These functions are affected: CONVERT_TZ(), DATE_ADD(), DATE_SUB(), DAYOFYEAR(), LAST_DAY(), TIMESTAMPDIFF(), TO_DAYS(), TO_SECONDS(), WEEK(), WEEKDAY(), WEEKOFYEAR(), YEARWEEK(). Because this changes date-handling behavior in General Availability-status series MySQL 5.1, the change was reverted in 5.1.62.

you can also do this

```
     SELECT ADDDATE('2013-07-19', 31);
```

Comment: Result : 323031332d30382d3139